# Bash: execute a command on all files with extension recursively

Tags: bash, recursion, find, haml, erb

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
herbalizer file_name.haml > file_name.erb
```

Here the `file_name.haml` is the file name, obviously.

How can I apply this command to all `haml` files in current directory recursively to all sub-directories? Filename should stay the same as mentioned above, so applying on `abc.haml` would be `herbalizer abc.haml > abc.erb`

So far: `find . -type f -exec herbalizer {} \;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close. You can use `basename` to strip the extension of the name of each file you find:

```
find . -type f -name \*.haml -exec sh -c 'herbalizer "{}" > "$(dirname {})/$(basename {} .haml).erb"' \;
```

I wrapped the i/o redirection in a shell command line. Filenames are enclosed in quotes in case a filename or path component contains spaces.

PS. That got you the job done, but it wasn't very elegant; so here's an alternative that uses bash's built-in substitution:

```
find . -type f -name \*.haml -exec bash -c 'FN="{}"; herbalizer "{}" > "${FN%.haml}.erb"' \;
```

Comment: Sorry, I overdid it with the quoting. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you, when applying to current dir, looks like the tree is no longer maintained. Haml Files are deleted and new files are created in current dir instead of their respective dir.

Comment: As if the scope given is always the current dir and not the dir where the files actually is.

Comment: Got it. Just a sec, let me test the solution.

Comment: This should do it, try again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `basename`, `dirname` and `find` to get your desired results:

```
find . -type f -name "*.haml" | while read fname
> do
> herbalizer ${fname} > $(dirname $fname)/$(basename $fname .haml).erb
> done
```

Another simple method as suggested in the comments sections by @Dummy00001 is:

```
find . -type f -name "*.haml" | while read fname
> do
> herbalizer ${fname} > ${fname%.haml}.erb
> done
```

Further reference: [Parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF)

Comment: You can replace the `$(dirname $fname)/$(basename $fname .haml).erb` with `${fname%.haml}.erb`.